# Exception in quantization aware training for faster rcnn

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am getting

```
File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/quantize/python/fold_batch_norms.py", line 338, in _ComputeBatchNormCorrections
    match.moving_variance_tensor + match.batch_epsilon)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

[image]
Exception while doing quantization aware training using tensorflow object detection api on faster rcnn architecture.
I was able to succesfully get it working for ssd mobilenet architecture. I am using TF 1.11.0 on GPU and master branch of object detection api.
I added

```
graph_rewriter {
  quantization {
    delay: 48
    weight_bits: 8
    activation_bits: 8
  }
}
```

to my pipeline.config file for quantization. I tried to set --fine_tune_batch_norm=true but it didn't help.

Comment: I have the same problem (and I am using Tensorflow 1.12), did you find any solution ?